# Extracting and Writing Stuff in ChatGPT

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I want to be able to write prompts to and get the responses from ChatGPT from a console program in VS Code. It needs to be in real time as well. This means that if I ask a question, it should give the answer immediately.

I thought about using a plug-in of some kind, but I do not know any that can do this. I also thought of using the Dev console that you can access by pressing F12 similar to what is shown in "Getting and setting data on a web page with JavaScript | Coding tutorial" by deeplizard. I thought that maybe I could extract the answers and write questions using this, but I don't know how I can then send this info to the VS code application. I also don't know what specific code I would need to make it work. Like how I would I get the specific response I want instead of the wrong one.

If you have any ideas, please tell me. It would also be very helpful to include some code if it needs it because I am not that knowledgeable on the specific code needed in this.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking, and I'm not sure you really know what you want.  Are you looking for a "Jarvis" application (like thousands of others), or are do you want to write a program that uses the OpenAI APIs to ask specific questions?  And I should warn you, if you're just starting out, this may not be the right starting project.

Comment: I am kind of looking for a conversational AI that I can talk to in the VS Code console. I thought that maybe this would be the easiest way to do this, but I am not quite sure of other ways that are FREE. 

Also when you say beginner I don't exactly know what you mean. I am intermediate or maybe a bit higher in Javascript. However, I don't have much experience in conversational AI as I cannot find any good websites or tutorials on how to make one and can only find tools to do so that cost money.

Answer (score 0):

````
 openai.api_key = 'Your api key'
 
 def generate_text(prompt):
     response = openai.Completion.create(
         engine="text-davinci-003",
         prompt=prompt,
         temperature=0.5,
         max_tokens=100,
         n=1,
         stop=None,
         frequency_penalty=0,
         presence_penalty=0
     )
 
     message = response.choices[0].text.strip()

     return message
 
 prompt=input("Enter the input :")
 res=generate_text(prompt)
 print(res)```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have done something similar to this, but I don't think it works. You only get a short limited time to use this for free when making a new account, and after that it says an error that you reached your usage limit and doesn't allow you to use it. You can only use it indefinitely if you have a paid account. However, if I don't find a good way to this, I might just make a new account and use this for a short period of time.

Here is the tutorial I used to make mine which gave me the error: "Make Your Own AI Chatbot using the ChatGPT API - Simple, Easy and CHEAP!" made by atomic14

Comment: If you want to take advantage of the vast amount of work done by others in creating ChatGPT, then pay for it.  Simple.